# Knockout SPA: Different Layouts(Master pages)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm building SPA application with knockout.js .
Basically what i do is bind as current page a ko component depending on what is route.
It looks something like

```
<div id="currentPage" data-bind="component: { name: currentRoute.page,
                                              attr: currentRoute }>
</div>
```

This is for the current page and the whole picture whit the layout looks like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div data-bind="component: {name: "nav"}></div>
        <div data-bind="component: {name: "aside"}></div>     
        <div id="currentPage" data-bind="component: {  name: currentRoute.page, 
                                                       attr: currentRoute}">
        </div>
    </body
</html>
```

The problem is that i dont have one layout.. the other one looks like this (pseudo used)

```
 <html>
    <body>
         <wrapper>
               <currentPage>
         </wrapper>
    </body
</html>
```

So basically the first layout is not direct parent of the currentPage module but the second is..

The variants for dynamic layout changing that i can think of are

1. Specify the layout components in each page.. But i dont think it is good idea cause i will be writing the same code over and over and will not be able to persist the state in the layout component because of when i change the next page the layout will be recreated( not fully but enough to loose the state )
2. The layout is separate from the currentPage component so only the currentComponent binding will be changed.. this is perfect for persisting state in layout but not good when i have variant where i want different layout for example which is wrapper around the componentBinding..

I'll be very happy if some one shares fresh ideas how to solve such problems.

Answer (score 0):

In knockout if any part of view is to be dynamically changed you got to have bindings attached to the view. You say that the outer layout of the page is dependent on the inner page being displayed, so logically I consider it part of that page view definition. That is why I would not look for some special way to handle this case.

If I am not missing something, the reasonable thing to do in this case is to just include layout in each page. You could then handle repetitive code by using "traditional" approach using knockout templates (especially Note 5 on dynamic templates from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) and code extraction.

Completely other approach you might want to take is to put all layouts in master page and then control them by using bindings like "if" and "visible".

Comment: I can not define the layout in every page cause i need to persist state. I have updated my question for more clarity